# How to set retryPolicy as an ARM Template Variable

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

i'm creating an Azure App that uses several Azure Functions. I want to have a custom retryPolicy that all those functions will use. To avoid duplicating code i wanted to define my retryPolicy as a variable or parameter. However i find it confusing to do so.

Acording to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates):

```
Variables:      Values that are used as JSON fragments in the template to simplify template language expressions.
```

So it seems that a variable is what i'm looking for. But how do i define the type so it matches the one i need, in order to be able to do this:

```
"retryPolicy": "[variables('myPolicy')]"
```

Comment: The question is not really clear. Who is consuming this `retryPolicy` setting? is it your own code? in an ARM template you can only specify string name-value pairs for configuring your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable in variables configuration of your template like this:

```
"variables": {
  "myPolicy": {},
  ...
}
```

You can set up the policy function in {}, and myPolicy variable can be used duplicate as `variables('myPolicy')`.

For more information about variables you can read document [Variables section of Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-templates-variables) .

Comment: How do i "set up the policy function"? Say, i want a retryPolicy, with `"interval": "PT7S", "count": 5, "type": "exponential"`

Comment: You can set up the function as you want. With the feathers you provided, you can make set up as: `"myPolicy": { "interval": "PT75", "count" 5, "type": "exponential" }`. I strongly recommend that you take a look at the link I posted in the answer. All in all, there is only you know what you really want.

Comment: @Kuczi Hi, if you take a try and get the right variable definition you want?